# Autoclose dialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to autoclose dialog a few seconds after opening. The solution that I found is to call `Navigator.of(context).pop();` delayed and it works. But the problem occurs if I closed it manually (by clicking outside) before the execution of the Navigator.pop command. Then Navigator.pop just closes the app and I see just a black screen.
I need a way to destroy this delay on closing the dialog or to find another workaround.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext builderContext) {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });

    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      title: Text('Title'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Text('Content'),
      ),
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a [Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) to achieve this. You can cancel the timer whenever you want.

Declare a timer property in your class:

```
Timer _timer;
```

And change your showDialog code like:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext builderContext) {
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });

    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      title: Text('Title'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Text('Content'),
      ),
   );
  }
).then((val){
  if (_timer.isActive) {
    _timer.cancel();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you are using the **wrong** `context`.

Try to change the `context` you are using in the "pop"

You have this `BuildContext builderContext`, use **that** builderContext like:

```
Navigator.of(builderContext).pop();
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's the difference? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can use different way of executing pop() request using Timer

```
_timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: _timerTimeoutInterval), () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
});
```

And in case you  want to cancel the timer you can call this:

```
if (_timer != null && _timer.isActive) {
  _timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: You can close it manually by creating button and executing Navigator pop method in that button's onPress callback.

Comment: Yes, but I want to close it by clicking outside.

Comment: Ahhhh sorry, I read the question wrong. In order to close the dialog and cancel that execution of a pop, you need to use timer, that can be cancelled on demand. I will edit my initial answer.