# How to dismiss a flutter dialog automatically, and navigate back?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dialog

I'm working on a `website` made in `Flutter`. I want that after some action is completed successfully, a `dialog` is displayed, it closes automatically, and it goes back to the previous page. My problem is that I can't make the following `error` disappear.

```
Error: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
```

This is my code.

```
showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
        builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
          Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
            Navigator.of(buildContext).pop();
            context.router.navigateBack();
          });
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text(AppGlobals.invalidFieldsText),
            content: const SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Text(AppGlobals.invalidFieldsDescriptionText)),
          );
        },
      );
```

If instead of closing the `dialog` automatically, I use a `button` to trigger, the error disappears.

```
showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
        builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text(AppGlobals.invalidFieldsText),
            content: const SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Text(AppGlobals.invalidFieldsDescriptionText)),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(AppGlobals.closeText),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(buildContext).pop();
                  context.navigateBack();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
```

I tried to find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548153/flutter-navigator-ofcontext-pop-vs-navigator-popcontext-difference), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683524/how-to-dismiss-flutter-dialog), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61307264/autoclose-dialog-in-flutter), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61424636/flutter-looking-up-a-deactivated-widgets-ancestor-is-unsafe), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617432/looking-up-a-deactivated-widgets-ancestor-is-unsafe) but I couldn't solve the problem. please help.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the widget tree has already been disposed of when the dialogue is supposed to be closed automatically after a predetermined length of time, which prevents Flutter from going back to the previous page.

Hence you can consider using a `StatefulWidget` to display the dialog and use the dispose function to stop the timer when the widget is removed.

Example:

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  Timer? _timer;

  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        _timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          Navigator.of(context).pop(); // navigate back
        });
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Dialog'),
          content: const Text('Dialog content'),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel(); // cancel timer when widget is removed
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _showDialog,
          child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the solution to my problem with the help of your answer. I was already calling the `showDialog` method inside a `StatefulWidget`. Instead of using the `.pop` method twice, the second time I replace it with the `navigateBack` method, because I'm using `Nested Navigation`. The main change was to declare the `Timer` variable separately, and dispose it when the view is removed. Thank you so much!!!.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `Future.delayed()` method to close the dialog automatically and `Navigator.of(context).pop()` to go back to the previous page.

```
// Show dialog
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      Navigator.of(buildContext).pop(); // close the dialog
      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // navigate back to the previous page
    });
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text(AppGlobals.invalidFieldsText),
      content: const SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Text(AppGlobals.invalidFieldsDescriptionText),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: It does not work. Now i have the error "Error: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct)."

Comment: @Idiaz997 above code contains twice the `Navigator.of(context).pop();  `. Just use once  Also make sure that you are calling showDialog() within a StatefulWidget .

Comment: If I only use one, the error disappears, but I don't go back to the previous page, the page from which the dialog was displayed remains.

Comment: @Idiaz997 above code shoud work . If not, could you provide your stateful widget code?

Comment: As you mentioned, the dialog is called within `StatefulWidget`. With the help of @BouncyBits's answer, I found the solution. it was to declare the `Timer` variable separately, and dispose it when the view is removed, as his answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'))`. Replace the `'/'` with your route name & voila!

Be careful, when you were calling this `Navigator.of(buildContext).pop()`, that passes the build context of the dialog builder; Not the root app context.

Key difference is using the default lowercase `context` which always refers to the app's main context. You were also trying to navigate again after your first `.pop()` which isn't possible because the widget (dialog) will close & will no longer be mounted.

Comment: I can't use popUntil because the view from which the dialog is fired is built from different views. So I wouldn't know which route name to use.